# Dihaloalkane reaction with sodamide/ammonia

Tags: organic-chemistry, reagents

> In the following sequence of reactions:
>
> $$\ce{CH3-CH2-CH2-I ->[\text{Alc.}~KOH] \textbf{A} ->[Br2] \textbf{B} ->[NaNH2/NH3] \textbf{C}}$$
>
> the product **C** is:
>
> 1. alkene
> 2. alkanol
> 3. alkyne
> 4. alkylamine

I haven't really came across a reagent $\ce{NaNH2}/\ce{NH3}$ in my whole session. Well, I have got **B** which is $\ce{CH3-CH(Br)-CH2-Br}.$

Then, how do I proceed next? How will my substrate  react with that reagent and what product will I achieve?

Comment: Google is your friend! Search sodamide and all will be revealed.

Comment: ...or go to a chapter on Alkynes.

Comment: @SiddharthBisht Sorry, two identical naming schemes based on capital letters for the compounds and the list of multiple choices drives me crazy. I changed the latter to the numbered list for the sake of sanity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were correct up to this point, the strong base alcoholic KOH sets off elimination instead of substitution so you will not get an alcohol.
Accordingly your products **A** (presumably propene) and **B** are correct.

The amide/ammonia is an even stronger base than alcoholic KOH and will also produce elimination.  With a vicinal dihalide like your **B**, there is an added twist.  Read [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/09%3A_Alkynes_-_An_Introduction_to_Organic_Synthesis/9.03%3A_Preparation_of_Alkynes_-_Elimination_Reactions_of_Dihalides) to find out what happens.